# Help on a specific usage of こそ

Tags: grammar

> 好きこそものの上手なれ。
>   We tend to be good at those things we like. /
>   People become best at what they love the most.

How does the こそ work here? Is this use of こそ common outside of proverbs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit in revision 4: If you are interested in this proverb, do not miss the [answer by Matt](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4593/15) to another question, where he cites an earlier form of the proverb.*

*Edit in revision 2: I rewrote the answer completely to give a more detailed explanation.  If you prefer a shorter answer, see the [old revision](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/4482/1).*

こそ signifies emphasis.  In other words, it adds the meaning of exclusiveness (as sawa wrote in a comment to this answer).  It is not archaic, and it is common to see こそ outside of proverbs or set phrases (see Paul Richter’s answer for examples).  In this answer, I will try to explain 好きこそものの上手なれ, focusing on the role of こそ.

Without こそ, the sentence would be

> 好きはものの上手なり。  Liking makes mastery.

好き means the action of liking something, just as in modern Japanese.  [ものの[上手]{じょうず}](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E7%89%A9%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8A%E6%89%8B&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0ss) is an archaic phrase which means a person who is very skilled at something.  なり is a copula in classical Japanese.  Therefore the literal meaning of the sentence above is roughly “Liking = A very skilled person,” but obviously this does not make sense because an action is not a person.  I think that it means “Liking makes a very skilled person,” or in short, “Liking makes mastery,” but I do not know the exact reason this “action = person” construct can be used.

Now we add こそ and the sentence becomes

> 好き**こそ**ものの上手なれ。  *It is* liking *that* makes mastery.

好きこそ means “liking, and nothing else.”  So the sentence means that liking and not anything else (such as aptitude) makes mastery.  A similar meaning can be expressed in English using a [cleft sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence) “It is … that …” like the sentence above.

I changed the auxiliary verb なり at the end of sentence to なれ when I added こそ.  As Chocolate pointed out in a comment, this is an instance of the grammatical phenomenon called 係り結び.  In classical Japanese, when a phrase/clause ending with particle こそ modifies a conjugating word at the end of a sentence, that conjugating word takes 已然形 instead of 終止形.  Similarly, when a phrase/clause ending with one of particles ぞ, なむ, や, and か modifies a conjugating word at the end of a sentence, that conjugating word takes 連体形.  This phenomenon is called 係り結び.

Comment: You are absolutely right. In other words, `こそ` adds the meaning of exclusiveness.

Comment: Thank you for your very interesting link to Wikipedia. I wasn't even aware that that was a thing, but we do it so much in English! I never even realized!

Comment: 「こそ～なれ」で、古典でやった「かかり結び」か何かのセットフレーズではないのですよね・・・？「ほたるのひかり」の歌詞の「いま'こそ'わかれ'め'」っていうのに似てますけど関係ない・・？（話がずれてたらすみません・・）

Comment: @Chocolate: Yes, こそ…なれ in 好きこそものの上手なれ is a 係り結び, and that is why the sentence ends with 已然形 “なれ” instead of 終止形 “なり.”  But I thought that that would be too much for an answer to the current question.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: You could always just add it at the end of your answer as a supplement.

Comment: i didn't realize this もの was a person. that makes a lot more sense now. thank you.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Actually, I completely forgot that 係り結び is in force here; I interpreted なれ as the imperative.

Comment: I rewrote the answer to include a more proper explanation of こそ in 好きこそものの上手なれ, including 係り結び.

Comment: @yadokari: Although it is true that もの sometimes means a person, I did not say that もの in this sentence means a person.  ものの上手 is a person, but I suspect that もの in ものの上手 just means things.  (But I am bad at Middle Japanese, so do not trust my words.)

Answer (score 2):

It expresses the idea of "as much as" or "to the degree that", referring specifically to the most/best such thing: *"The most A is the most B"*

<del>We excel in a thing as much as we like it.
    We excel in a thing to the degree that we like it.</del>

Your translation "People become best at what they love the most." expresses this well in the relationship between *best* and *most*.

Here are some examples I found:

```
短い条文こそ奥が深い
やさしい曲こそ深い
知識は使ってこそ技術になる
速いランナーこそ要注意
```

So "The shortest law has the deepest meaning", etc.

<del>If the subject is a single thing that can not vary in degree, こそ simply serves as emphasis.</del>

If used with things that vary not in degree but possibility, it emphasizes that the thing is  best/most likely by contrast with the other *implicit* possibilities.

```
彼こそ社長になるべき -> He, if anyone, should be president (instead of the current guy).
今年こそ海外に行きます -> This year, for once, I will go overseas (after giving up every year until now).
```

EDIT:clarified the indication of "the most" in light of sawa's comment.

Comment: I think you are confusing こそ with ほど.

Comment: @paul, if it is not a trouble, could you provide translations for the examples you gave? thank you.